# Encrypting a columnar transposition cipher

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x, multiple-columns, transpose

I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt a columnar transposition cipher in Python given a plaintext uppercase string and a number key of any length. For example, if the key is 3124 and the string is 'IHAVETWOCATS', it would organize the string like so:

```
3124
IHAV
ETWO
CATS
```

and then return the characters in column 1 first, then column 2, etc, until finally returning the encrypted string `'HTAAWTIECVOS'`. So far I know that I'll need to use an accumulator, and I've been toying with the idea of using a dictionary, but I'm just completely stuck. These are some of the functions I've tried:

```
def columnar(plaintext,key):
    cipher=''
    acc=0
    for i in range(len(key)):
        while acc<(len(plaintext)/len(key)):
            cipher=cipher+plaintext[i+acc*5]
            acc=acc+1
    return(cipher)
```

^This only returns a few letters, not a string of appropriate length.

`def columnar(plaintext,key)
    values={}
    seqlist=[]
    nextvalue=1
    indices=rand(len(key))
    for letter in plaintext:
        for i in indices:
            if letter==key[i]:
                values[i]=nextvalue
                nextvalue=nextvalue+1
    for i in indices:
        seqlist.append(values[i])
    return seqlist`

^The above function returns a KeyError: 0 error. 
Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def split_len(seq, length):
    return [seq[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)]

def encode(key, plaintext):

    order = {
        int(val): num for num, val in enumerate(key)
    }

    ciphertext = ''
    for index in sorted(order.keys()):
        for part in split_len(plaintext, len(key)):
            try:
                ciphertext += part[order[index]]
            except IndexError:
                continue

    return ciphertext

print(encode('3214', 'IHAVETWOCATS'))
#>>> HTAAWTIECVOS
```

`split_len` is by Ian Bicking

So i split the code into chunks with `split_len` then use dictionary comprehension to just get correct order of indexes and finally i concatanate the letters in that order.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, this function is hardwired to only work for key '3124' and plaintext 'IHAVETWOCATS'. How would I modify this function to accommodate any string and any key? Put it in the parameters?

Comment: @hooliaquoolia: i have edited the code and wrapped it into function

Answer (score 1):

```
def encode(txt,key):
    sz = len(key)  # how big are the columns 
    cols = list(map("".join,zip(*zip(*[iter(txt)]*sz)))) # list partitioned into columns
    return "".join([cols[key.index(str(c))] for c in range(1,sz+1)])



encoded = encode("IHAVETWOCATS","3124")
print encoded
```

is probably how I would do it

Comment: This only works if the length of text is multiplication of key length. Try it with the same text and "31245" key.

Comment: I copied and pasted this but I got the error: "'map' object is not subscriptable." Is there a way to take the map object out of the join?

Comment: @aseeon yes you are correct ...I could easily switch it to izip_longest to resolve that if that is a valid senario ..

Comment: @hooliaquoolia fixed that for you ..... in my version of python map returns a list ... but i forgot that in current iterations it returns a iterator