# How to Convert a String to 2d array in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement the Columnar Transposition Algorithm in python. So I need to convert the input string to 2d array of characters. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Encrypting a columnar transposition cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872411/encrypting-a-columnar-transposition-cipher) : Look at the split_len function

```
def split_len(seq, length):
    return [seq[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)]

def encode(key, plaintext):

    order = {
        int(val): num for num, val in enumerate(key)
    }

    ciphertext = ''
    for index in sorted(order.keys()):
        for part in split_len(plaintext, len(key)):
            try:
                ciphertext += part[order[index]]
            except IndexError:
                continue

    return ciphertext

print(encode('3214', 'IHAVETWOCATS'))
#>>> HTAAWTIECVOS
```

Comment: How does the dictionary comprehension is working? How its is storing the index of each key? I am not getting it